# My Jbutton is not adding the fetched data from Jtextfield and print the data to Jtable

Tags: java

```
private void btn_addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    add fdata = new add();

    fdata.setVisible(true);
    fdata.setSize(400, 400);
}


private void jaddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    int sid = Integer.parseInt(tfsid.getText());
    String sname = tfsname.getText();
    int squantity = Integer.parseInt(tfsquantity.getText());
    String datee = tfdate.getText();

    dashboard dash = new dashboard();

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dash.data_table.getModel();
    model.addRow(new Object[]{
        sid,sname,squantity,datee
    });
}
```

Comment: how is the `jaddActionPerformed` called ?

Comment: jadd is the variable name of my JButton(Add)

Comment: That's not what I asked

Comment: Sir , Honestly I dont know what you mean , coz I directly code the syntax  in my jaddActionPerformed .

Comment: ther is no call to `jaddActionPerformed` in the current code